# How to download an image by http and show it to user after it has been loaded?

Tags: image, http, dart, flutter

I'm trying to load an image from the server, the problem is I want to show `CircularProgressIndicator` by the time that the image is loading. so what came to my mind is to get the image separately instead of showing it by `Image.network`. so now I get the image from the server using `http.get`. how can I show the received value? should I use the `response.bodyBytes`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [cached_network_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image)

Comment: Thanks. how can I do this for downloading other file types?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a `CachedNetworkImage` widget, [Here](https://flutter.io/cookbook/images/cached-images/) you can find and example...

Hope it helps.